# Kurzweil-Stellmacher. The Theory of Finite Groups. Exercise 1.1.13 hint request

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm afraid I would need a **hint** to solve the following

**Exercise 13:** Let $G$ be a finite group and $A$ a subgroup. If $\{A^x\mid x\in G\} = \{A_1, \dots, A_n\}$ then $\langle A_1, \dots, A_n\rangle = A_1\cdots A_n$.

**My attempt:** Re-write $A_{\sigma(1)}\cdots A_{\sigma(n)}$ as a conjugate of $A_1\cdots A_n$.

**Note:** As indicated in the title, the exercise appears in the first section of the book, before the concepts of homomorphism and normal subgroup have been presented. At this point, the reader is only familiar with the definitions of group and subgroup, the Lagrange theorem, the $HK=KH$ condition, and transversal sets. A previous exercise shows that the union of all conjugates of a proper subgroup is a proper subset of the group. Another, that $G=AA^g\implies G=A$.

**Information:** Someone provided me with an approach using Character Theory. However, the expectation is for an elementary argument.

Comment: 20 years ago I have also struggled with this exercise, which is, in hindsight, extraordinary difficult compared to the others. In the end, I found a proof by induction on the number of factors in a product of elements. I believe there is also a paper on such kind of statements. I will try to find it.

Comment: Here is the analogous statement for field extensions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4151428/normal-closure-as-the-compositum-of-conjugates

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Many thanks. I've completed the details and now the solution is clear. Thanks for link too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $x\in A_i$ and $y\in A_j$ with $i>j$. Then $xy=y(y^{-1}xy)$ with $y^{-1}xy\in A_k$ for some $k$. Doing some induction, you find $x'\in A_s$ and $y'\in A_t$ with $xy=x'y'$ and $s<t$. Now do another induction to handle more than two factors.

Comment: See also the answer by Derek Holt here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173457/is-the-product-of-all-conjugates-of-some-subgroup-independent-of-the-order

Answer (score 4):

The problem also appears in B. Huppert, "Endliche Gruppen I", as problem 2 in chapter 1. Huppert provides a hint and a reference to a paper by Itô and Szép, "Über die Faktorisation von Gruppen", Acta Sci. Math. Szeged 16, 229-231 (1955).

The hint goes as follows (transcribed):
For each decomposition $x = x_{i_1} x_{i_2} \cdots x_{i_s}$ with $x_{i_j} \in A_{i_j}$ one associates the $s$-tuple $m(x) = (i_1, i_2, \dots, i_s)$. Now order these tuples by their length, and for tuples of equal length by lexicographic order. Consider an $x$ that cannot be written in the desired form, $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$ with $a_i \in A_i$, and consider a decomposition of $x$ with minimal $m(x)$.

Comment: For those curious, the paper by Itô and Szép is here: [link](http://pub.acta.hu/acta/showCustomerArticle.action?id=6418&dataObjectType=article&returnAction=showCustomerVolume&sessionDataSetId=41ff5fc6793fff96&style=). The proof there goes along the lines of the hint given by Huppert.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. It shows us the origin of this interesting property! Thank you!